# Git - Undo a commit on Team Explorer Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-reset, team-explorer

I just did a huge commit and when I push it, I get this error:

> RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10054

I believe I get this error because my commit is too big to push, so I want to try smaller commits, but first I need to undo the current commit. My question is how do I do that in Visual Studio Team Explorer? Here is a screenshot, do I want to Reset and Keep changes? I don't want to do anything to mess up or lose code.

[image]

Comment: --mixed seems like this is what i want to accomplish what I want to do, can someone confirm that I am right?

Comment: Use git bash and straightaway do soft reset. Use your post which you have posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937046/git-undo-commit-git-reset-soft-does-nothing/59937091#59937091

Comment: And I see some local items in your changes. You could just ignore those local items ;)

Answer (score 3):

To reset HEAD back one commit and *keep* the changes so you can break it up into smaller commits, choose "Reset and Keep Changes (--mixed)".  This runs "git reset --mixed" on the command line, which moves the HEAD ref but leaves the workdir alone.  Therefore all of your changed files will appear in the Changes page.

The other option (--hard), will reset both the HEAD ref and update the workdir to match the repository at that commit.  This would discard your changes.

To clarify, you'll want to view history for your branch and choose reset on the commit just *before* your new commit.  In other words, you are resetting HEAD to that parent commit, but leaving the workdir matching your current commit.  This will result in all changes in that commit being available in the workdir for subdivision into new commits.

Hope this helps.