# Git - undo commit (git reset --soft) does nothing

Tags: git, git-reset

I just did a commit and realized I need to undo the commit without deleting any changes....how would I do that? I have tried `git reset --soft` and that did nothing, no errors nothing, when I enter that command, literally nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --soft` implies `HEAD`, but you want to go back to the commit *before* `HEAD`, thus :

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

The advantage of this way is you can reset softly for `n` latest commits, just let the command know expected number of commits to reset softly.

For example, to reset softly last two commits:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

You might also want to learn about [various modes of reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24569160/5343790).

Comment: by doing that they are now unstaged changes....what would happen if i unstaged them?

Comment: they are already unstaged you are saying so why unstage again?

Comment: Just re-stage them with `git add .`, but if you didn't want to unstage them, you could have used `--mixed` (implied) instead of `--soft`, so `git reset HEAD^`